# Query help - joining two tables with subset based on column values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql

Lets say I have two tables as such:

```
People

Id   Name       FirstDate LastDate
--   --------   --------- --------
A1   Bob        1/1/2007  5/6/2007
A2   Joe        1/4/2008  9/1/2008
..   ..         ...       ...

PiesBaked

Name        Date       Value
--------    ----       -----
Bob         1/1/2007    7
Bob         1/2/2007    9
..          ...        ...
Joe         ...        ...
```

How can I construct a view that subsets PiesBaked to First/Last Date for a Name

```
Result

Id   Name    Date      Value
--   ----    ----      -----
A1   Bob     1/1/2007   7
A1   Bob     1/2/2007   9
..    ..     ...        ...
A1   Bob     5/6/2007   ...
..   ...     ...        ...
```

Comment: could you explain how those are related? is first - last date a timespan?

Comment: Can you expand your desired results a bit?  What are you expecting between 1/2/2007 and 5/6/2007?  what will the `value` be for 5/6/2007?

Comment: I would hope that "Name" is not the foreign key.

Comment: @cularis - correct.  FirstDate is always before (in the past) relative to LastDate.  So perhaps these are the bounds of dates that someone is eligible to bake pies for a contest...but perhaps these people baked some pies before and after that date (captured in PiesBaked)...I'm just trying to get information about pies baked while "eligible"

Comment: @Abe - I'm expecting a lookup into the PiesBaked table for Dates >= FirstDate and <= LastDate for a given person

Comment: @Narnian - Name is not unique in PiesBaked.  PiesBaked has no key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.Id, a.Name, b.Date, b.Value
  FROM People a INNER JOIN PiesBaked b
    ON a.Name = b.Name
   AND b.Date BETWEEN a.FirstDate AND a.LastDate
```

Comment: Same solution as mine :), but I guess you should sort the result

Comment: I did not provide the answer, Cybernate did. He deserves the thanks ;)

Comment: yikes...meant to say @Cybernate!  need coffee

Answer (score 3):

```
select p.id, p.name, pb.Date, pb.value
  from people p
 inner join piesBaked pb 
         on pb.name = p.name 
        and pb.date between p.firstDate and p.lastDate
 order by p.id, pb.Date
```